# how to display featured = 'Yes' above all post first then rest?

Tags: php, mysql

ok so here my this codes working just fine but what exactly i wish to get is first display the results where post_featured ='Yes' and not older than 10 days?

if any post_featured has value **Yes** it remains on top but only if its not older than 10 days i tried order by but somehow it wont work

my codes

```
$search_fields = array('post_area','post_category','post_type'); 
$and_clause = array(); 
$params = array();

foreach($search_fields as $field){
    if(isset($_GET[$field]) && $_GET[$field] != 'All'){
        $and_clause[] = "`$field` = :$field";
        $params[] = array(":$field",$_GET[$field],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}

$where_clause = '';
if(!empty($and_clause)){
    $where_clause = "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $and_clause);
}

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts $where_clause";

if(empty($params)){
    $stmt = $db->query($query);
}else{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    foreach($params as $param)    {
        $stmt->bindValue($param[0],$param[1],$param[2]);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
}

$total = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 

$params[] = array(':per_page',$per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$params[] = array(':offset',$offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts $where_clause ORDER BY postID DESC LIMIT :per_page OFFSET :offset";

if(empty($params)){
    $stmt = $db->query($query);
}else{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    foreach($params as $param){
        $stmt->bindValue($param[0],$param[1],$param[2]);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
}
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: im using  timestamp as created timestamp  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: So you want all the yes in the last 10 days ordered by descending timestamp then all the yes and no by descending timestamp? - assuming there are only yes and no values for post_featured.

Comment: yes @P.Salmon all records display as usual but on top should be those first where post_featured has value Yes but created time not more than 10 days else if it older then no need to display those post_featured value with 'Yes' on top

Comment: could someone help on this? @P.Salmon u there?

Answer (score 0):

Given table t

```
+------+---------------+------------+
| id   | post_featured | dte        |
+------+---------------+------------+
|    1 | yes           | 2016-07-15 |
|    2 | no            | 2016-07-15 |
|    3 | yes           | 2016-07-14 |
|    4 | yes           | 2016-06-15 |
|    5 | no            | 2016-06-15 |
|    1 | yes           | 2016-06-14 |
+------+---------------+------------+
```

and a requirement to sort in 2 ways you could

```
select t.*,
        case when t.post_featured = 'yes' and dte >= date_add(curdate() ,interval -10 day) then 1
        else 2
        end as srce
 from t
 order  by srce asc,id desc;
```

result

```
+------+---------------+------------+------+
| id   | post_featured | dte        | srce |
+------+---------------+------------+------+
|    3 | yes           | 2016-07-14 |    1 |
|    1 | yes           | 2016-07-15 |    1 |
|    5 | no            | 2016-06-15 |    2 |
|    4 | yes           | 2016-06-15 |    2 |
|    2 | no            | 2016-07-15 |    2 |
|    1 | yes           | 2016-06-14 |    2 |
+------+---------------+------------+------+
```